# Idiomatic ruby to calculate distance to points on a graph

Tags: algorithm, ruby, graph

Can this code be made more like idiomatic ruby using methods such as map or inject?

`@random_tour` is a variable length array of points on a graph:
`[[0, 0], [2, 1], [4, 3]]`

I want to calculate the distance to reach each point using the manhattan distance (number of moves horizontally + number of moves vertically).

For example, starting at `[0, 0]` - the next point `[2, 1]` is 2 moves horizontally, 1 move vertically which is 3 moves. The next point is `[4, 3]` which is 4 moves away from the last. Total number of moves is 7.

```
def cost
  i = 0
  total_cost = 0
  while i < @random_tour.length - 1 do
    total_cost += (@random_tour[i + 1][0] - @random_tour[i][0]).abs + (@random_tour[i + 1][1] - @random_tour[i][1]).abs
    i += 1
  end
  total_cost
end
```

Comment: Just to post an annoying comment: you might use a different or larger set as an example to show that negative change in distance is still counted as a positive (otherwise you're just subtracting first from last).

Answer (score 4):

`Enumerable.each_cons(n)` will pass the array items in groups of n, using a sliding window.  So [pt1, pt2], [pt2, pt3], [pt3, pt4], etc.

After that you can use `inject` to calculate the distance and sum the points.

```
def manhattan(pt1, pt2)
  (pt1[0]-pt2[0]).abs + (pt1[1]-pt2[1]).abs
end

def cost
  @random_tour
    .each_cons(2)
    .inject(0) { |sum, pts| sum + manhattan(pts[0], pts[1]) }
end
```

Comment: +1 for `each_cons` – it's a little-known, often useful method which saves so much time.

Comment: Note that you can unpack the array in the block: `{ |sum, (x, y)| sum + manhattan(x, y) }`.

Comment: I noticed that in your code.  I had attempted to do it originally, but didn't know the correct syntax.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that is too imperative, it's based on indexes, accumulators and in-place updates. Instead, a more declarative tries to apply transformations to immutable streams of data.

@Zack has already pointed you to [each_cons(2)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to get consecutive pair-wise combinations. I'd write it slightly different, though: I'd isolate the calculation of Manhattan distances and the total sum. You may use [lazy enumerables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) if the intermediate array happens to be a problem:

```
def cost
  @random_tour
    .each_cons(2)
    .map { |(x1, y1), (x2, y2)| (x2 - x1).abs + (y2 - y1).abs }
    .reduce(0, :+)
end
```

Comment: I like your solution. Extracting the distance function like Zack did, could make it an one-liner - `@random_tour.each_cons(2).map(&:manhattan_distance).reduce(0, :+)`.

Comment: Indeed, but that you'd have to add `manhattan_distance` to `Array` for that to work.

Comment: Or, alternatively, say `.map(&method(:manhattan_distance))`

Answer (score 0):

Only one tip for you: `zip`.

Whenever you see code that's exactly the same thing, but an index changes, `zip` (with a `map` and `inject`) could be useful. For example, in your situation, you'd replace this bit:

```
(@random_tour[i + 1][0] - @random_tour[i][0]).abs + (@random_tour[i + 1][1] - @random_tour[i][1]).abs
```

See how all that changes is the last index? You can change this easily, without really reducing readability, to this:

```
@random_tour[i + 1].zip(@random_tour[i]).map { |(end, start)| (end - start).abs }.inject(:+)
```

The benefit to this approach is that if you want to change the operation you're doing to the pairs, you only change it once; ditto for the places you're getting the pairs and the way you put them together. In addition, if you decide to change this to a 3D random walk, it'll Just Work® without you having to do a thing, because it automatically loops through every dimension.

If you want it to be even more expandable, try [`inject(:-)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) inside the `map` -- that is, `|p| p.inject(:-)` inside `map`'s block. In this case, it doesn't really make sense, but if you ever... I dunno, have more than one distance? Okay, yeah, it really doesn't make sense. I just like `inject`'s magic.